# Can I use hash values from another file?

Tags: perl, variables, hash

I have a hash in a perl file (lets call it test2.pl) like so:

```
our %hash1;

my %hash2 = {
    one   => ($hash1{"zero1"},  $hash1{"one1"}  ),
    two   => ($hash1{"one1"},   $hash1{"two1"}  ),
    three => ($hash1{"two1"},   $hash1{"three1"}),
    four  => ($hash1{"three1"}, $hash1{"six1"}  ),
    five  => ($hash1{"six1"},   $hash1{"one2"}  ),
    six   => ($hash1{"one2"},   $hash1{"two2"}  ),
    last  => ($hash1{"two2"},   $hash1{"last1"} ),
};
```

This is getting 6 `Use of uninitialized value in anonymous hash ({}) at test2.pl line 7.` errors (line 7 in the file corresponds to the `my %hash2` line and all the errors say line 7).

I can only assume this is because `%hash1` is defined in another file (test1.pl) which calls this file. I thought using `our` would be enough to define it. Do I have to initialise all the variables in the hash for this to work?

(I'm using brackets with the `our` as there are other variables I have declared there.)

Comment: @fxzuz I explained at the bottom of my post why I used the brackets around the %hash1 after the our.... I understand that for one thing you don't need them.

Comment: `use warnings` would have given you a clue about what the problem was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Perl, you define hashes as *even lists*. That means that they are delimited by **parens** not **braces**:

```
my %hash = (
  key1 => "value1",
  key2 => "value2",
);
my $anonHashRef = {
  key1 => "value1",
  key2 => "value2",
};
```

Curly braces create a new anonymous hash *reference*.

If you wan't to access the hash from another file, you should use a `package` declaration at the top:

```
package FooBar;
# Your %hash comes here
# it HAS to be GLOBAL, i.e. declared with `our`, not `my`
```

We can then `require` or `use` your file (although the filename and package name should preferably be the same) and access your hash as a package global:

In your main file:

```
use 'file2.pl';
my $element = $FooBar::hash{$key};
```

See the `Exporter` module for a nicer way use data structures in another namespace.

Comment: oooh that would explain a lot, thanks! A lot of the examples I've seen on the net use {} instead of () and I've been learning using perl for about 3 days so I assumed that was the way. I've been looking at how to do packages, too, so double bonus! :D cheers!

Comment: bladepanthera: Using {} instead of () will give you a _reference_ to a hash rather than the hash itself.

Comment: although I agree on using packages, I think it is worth to mention the default `main` package. It can especially be useful to access global variables from other files loaded by the `do` statement, e.g. `$main::myGlobalVarible`